# Issue deploying EKS cluster using Terraform and then installing Jenkins into that cluster using Helm

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, terraform, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I'm following along this tutorial: https://github.com/calvinliphc/terraform-jenkins?source=post_page-----ce1cf5594687--------------------------------

It has me apply the terraform from the provisions folder. I get an EKS cluster setup successfully in AWS. the 2nd part applies the terraform from the manage folder, which is supposed to install Jenkins onto that cluster. I can see the the Jenkins services created locally, but then it just keeps trying to run through the helm chart to set Jenkins up.

```
helm_release.jenkins: Still creating... [45m30s elapsed]
```

Eventually it times out:

```
Error: context deadline exceeded
│
│ with helm_release.jenkins,
│ on jenkins.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "jenkins":
│ 1: resource "helm_release" "jenkins" {
```

Any ideas on what I need to do to troubleshoot this? Is there a way to get more detailed logs from helm to debug?

I tried extending the timeout, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I figured the issue out. In the values.yaml, which is just the values for the Jenkins Helm Chart, there's one line:

```
configuration-as-code:1670.v564dc8b_982d0
```

That line is updated fairly often and if calling the old version, setting up Jenkins will fail. I just searched Google for the Jenkins Helm Chart, went to the repo, clicked on charts and copied in all of the values into my values.yaml. That ensured everything was up to date. The last step was to change the service type to LoadBalancer. Then I was able to bring up the EKS cluster with Jenkins running inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

In this code snippet, have you changed to use your own values:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "eks" {
  backend = "remote"
  config = {
    organization = "PEACEHAVENCORP"
    workspaces = {
      name = "terraform-jenkins-EKS-provision"
    }
  }
}
```

Mainly `organization` and `workspaces name`